# Tags in aspx file is not highlighted

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, aspx-user-control

I'm using VS2015. Whenever I create a webform, the tags in .aspx file doesn't highlight in general. 
SCREENSHOT.
[image]

But, whenever I add a new line after the control's name, the tags get highlighted as show in the screenshot.
[image]

What is the solution of this?